# url rewrites dynamic urls redirects - Magento

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm looking for htaccess lines that do the following

Redirect old existing urls to new url (301)

Example
www.example.com/categorya/categoryb/product.htm

TO

www.example.com/product.htm

There can be more category parts, or less, it all has to go to /product.htm (Magento).

Who can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting these rules in the htaccess file in your document root, preferably above any rules that you may already have there:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)/product.htm$ /product.htm [L,R=301]
```

---

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/[^/]+/([^.]+)\.htm$ /$1.htm [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering Jon Lin. We have 12000 products, so we will have to make it for each product? Can it be dynamic?

Comment: @JELLEJ is there some kind of pattern for what the `product.htm` files look like?

Comment: @John Lin, no there is not. It always end on some-text-here.htm dashes are not always there

Comment: Thanks Jon Lin, what about URLs that have a variable amount of categories?

Comment: @JELLEJ You can replace `[^/]+/[^/]+/` with `.+?/` if you don't care how many (as long as there is one) category directories there are.